# Garbage disposal Power source

Tags: electrical

I just replaced my garbage disposal following the instructions from a youtube video. I followed the instructions which to summarize were:
1. Flip the breaker to off 
2. Switch the garbage disposal unit. 
3. Turn the breaker on.
4. Test the garbage disposal.

The problem I had was when I turned the garbage disposal on there was a small pop and flash and the garbage disposal unit did not work. I'm assuming this had to do with the way I rewired the garbage disposal. When I rewired the disposal I tighten the ground and rewired black on black and white on white. I got the exact same model as the one I replaced and did the exact same thing as the existing installation. My assumption is the garbage disposal unit is fried although when I switched the power switch to on it made a noise as if it was going to work. Does anyone believe the same? Also, will I have to replace the hardwire. How can I tell if this still works? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The pop and flash was an arc, which could have been either a short circuit or a bad connection blowing apart.

If it occurred at the connections you made to the disposal, correcting those connections should solve the problem and the unit has almost certainly not been damaged. If it occurred elsewhere, you may have a larger problem.

If you have to ask, I would *strongly* recommend getting a friend who has more experience to help you correct this.

Comment: I agree wholly. Get help if you don't know what you are doing. YouTube is nothing to rely on if you have no experience at all.
More than likely you caused a short due to something touching. It's doubtful you ruined the unit.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "although when I switched the power switch to on it made a noise as if it was going to work", do you mean you can hear the motor hum when you turn on the power? If that's true, everything may still be as it should be, but something may be preventing the chopper from spinning. Did you maybe leave some screws inside the top opening when you installed it?